# Python VM arguments

Tags: python, eclipse, arguments, windows-xp

OS:WinXP
Python 2.6

A Python project in Eclipse, if you go to 'run configuration' arguments tab. There's a section for 'Python VM arguments (Python.exe)'. Does anyone know where to find a reference for what arguments does Python VM have? I tried keyword 'Python (VM or Virtual Machine) arguments' but couldn't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These would be the command line arguments to the python interpreter So the docs would be [standard python](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html)

ie the optional part after the python executable and before args in

> python [-BdEiOQsStuUvVWxX3?] [-c command | -m module-name | script | - ] [args]